# Prevent site being served from another domain via ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

One of our clients has a website we've found being served via another domain they are not in control of. This is possible if they set up an Apache VirtualHost on their server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.[theirdomain].com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ProxyPass / http://www.[ourdomain].com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.[ourdomain].com/
</VirtualHost>
```

How do we prevent them being able to serve our content from their domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really is a proxy, check the IP address of it from DNS. You can confirm you have the correct IP (or even seek for it) from the logs. Block it in the firewall or your web server's access control.

However, it's more likely that this foreign domain just points to the IP address of your client's web server and the site is the default virtual host on that server. In this case you could add a new catch-all default virtual host for serving requests with all unknown `Host:` headers.